# How get ListCollectionView's currentItem for ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" it's the last selectedItem?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I using MVVM,and ListBox' ItemsSource Binding ListCollectionView Type.

How get currentItem for  ListCollectionView that I wanna get  ListBox's the Last SelectedItem on SelectionMode="Multiple"

Currently,I can get first selectItem that be ListCollectionView's currentItem ,but cant get   the last SelectedItem be ListCollectionView's currentItem.

Can anyone help me? or tell me some solutions.

thanks helpe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Prism's Behavior:

```
public class LastSelectionBehavior:Behavior<ListBox>
{
    private ICollectionView _itemsSource;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        _itemsSource = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as ICollectionView;

        if (_itemsSource != null)
            AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged;
    }

    void AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            _itemsSource.MoveCurrentTo(e.AddedItems[0]);
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NamesView}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:LastSelectionBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: thaks Bill Zhang.I changed   "AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged" method then it can work,but When SelectionMode="Extended" ,would you give suggest to Get LastItem for currentItem ? thank you.

Comment: If SelectionMode="Extended", you have to consider the direction. When using Ctrl, either direction is ok since the AddedItems only contain one element. But when using Shift, you should consider whether selection up or down. If selection towards up, you should move current to e.AddedItems[0] and otherwise you should move current to e.AddedItems[e.AddedItems.Count-1]. To determine whether up or down is first get the index of AssociatedObject, index of e.AddedItems[0]. If first index is less than second, is down, otherwise, is up.

Comment: Incisive analysis,I benefited much.